# How do I set the title on the destination view controller during prepareForSegue:

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I want to simply set the title on my destination view controller so that it shows in its navigation controller's navigation bar in the prepareForSegue: method however setting its title or navigationItem like so:

`[segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"doesn't work"];
 [segue.destinationViewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"this either"];`

doesn't work possibly because the destination's view controller's view isn't loaded yet. Can I do this without creating a custom destination view controller?

Answer (score 11):

Try accessing your `ViewController` that is embedded in the `UINavigationController` like this. 
First you give your segue an identifier in the interface builder, then you access the segue in the `prepareForSegue` method and set the title by accessing the `topViewController` property of the navigation controller you segue to.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = 
           (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        YourViewController *destViewController = 
           (YourViewController* )[navController topViewController];

        destViewController.navgationItem.title.text = @"Your new title";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This wasn't exactly my problem nor does this solution work for me but it reminded me that the source view controller is in a container view which is then inside a navigation view controller. So I just had to reference the correct navigation controller in my stack of views.

Comment: Steve, can you elaborate on how you referenced the correct navigation controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a static title this can now (i.e., in Xcode 4.6.3) this can be done in Storyboard simply by setting the title in the nav bar on the relevant view controller.

If however you want the nav bar title to change according to what view is being segued to, e.g., a detail of a particular table row, as far as I know that needs to be set programmatically.

It took me FOREVER (newbie, sigh!) to figure out how to modify Julian Vogels' correct answer to call the key I wanted to use. Here's what worked:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {
        // Fetch Item
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *item = [self.groceries objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        // Configure Detail View Controller
        TPDetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.navigationItem.title = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
        [vc setItem:item];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for a segue into another UITableView

1. Set a public NSString property in the destination UITableViewController file.

   `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *navBarTitle;`
2. Override the setter in the .m file just to be sure.

   `- (void) setNavBarTitle:(NSString *)navBarTitle
     {
       _navBarTitle = navBarTitle;
     }`
3. In the originating tableView's segue method, pass whatever string you need in the title.

   `- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"userDetails"]) {
       UsersActivitiesTableViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
       //Get the index path of the cell the user just clicked
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       //Grab the object from the array of users if the next view requires a specific title for a user name etc.
       UserMO *thisUser = [self.users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       //Pass the string you want as the title to the public NSString property
       destinationController.navBarTitle = thisUser.name;
    }
   }`
4. And now for the important bit....
   In the destination controller, get the top controller of the view and set the title property, after the view is loaded, and before it has been displayed:

   `- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self.navigationController topViewController].title = self.navBarTitle;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

If the segue is a push segue - which it should be if you're using a UINavigationController - then the destination view controller is automatically added to the window hierarchy, and you don't even need to identify the UINavigationController:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueNameHere"]) {    
    [segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@"yourTitleHere"];
}
```